# jQuery countdown - accuracy

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, datetime

I'm using this simple plugin to show a simple countdown in my pages, what I would like is to keep it more accurate, cause somentimes it seems it isn't accurate.

This is the plugin:

```
/*
countdown is a simple jquery plugin for countdowns

Dual licensed under the MIT (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)
and GPL (http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php) licenses.

@source: http://github.com/rendro/countdown/
@autor: Robert Fleischmann
@version: 1.0.0
*/


(function() {

  (function($) {
    $.countdown = function(el, options) {
      var getDateData,
        _this = this;
      this.el = el;
      this.$el = $(el);
      this.$el.data("countdown", this);
      this.init = function() {
        _this.options = $.extend({}, $.countdown.defaultOptions, options);
        if (_this.options.refresh) {
          _this.interval = setInterval(function() {
            return _this.render();
          }, _this.options.refresh);
        }
        _this.render();
        return _this;
      };
      getDateData = function(endDate) {
        var dateData, diff;
        endDate = Date.parse($.isPlainObject(_this.options.date) ? _this.options.date : new Date(_this.options.date));
        diff = (endDate - Date.parse(new Date)) / 1000;


        if (diff < 0) {
          diff = 0;
          if (_this.interval) {
            _this.stop();
          }
        }
        dateData = {
          years: 0,
          days: 0,
          hours: 0,
          min: 0,
          sec: 0,
          millisec: 0
        };
        if (diff >= (365.25 * 86400)) {
          dateData.years = Math.floor(diff / (365.25 * 86400));
          diff -= dateData.years * 365.25 * 86400;
        }
        if (diff >= 86400) {
          dateData.days = Math.floor(diff / 86400);
          diff -= dateData.days * 86400 ;
        }
        if (diff >= 3600) {
          dateData.hours = Math.floor(diff / 3600);
          diff -= dateData.hours * 3600;
        }
        if (diff >= 60) {
          dateData.min = Math.floor(diff / 60);
          diff -= dateData.min * 60;
        }
        dateData.sec = diff;

        return dateData;
      };
      this.leadingZeros = function(num, length) {
        if (length == null) {
          length = 2;
        }
        num = String(num);
        while (num.length < length) {
          num = "0" + num;
        }
        return num;
      };
      this.update = function(newDate) {
        _this.options.date = newDate;
        return _this;
      };
      this.render = function() {
        _this.options.render.apply(_this, [getDateData(_this.options.date)]);
        return _this;
      };
      this.stop = function() {
        if (_this.interval) {
          clearInterval(_this.interval);
        }
        _this.interval = null;
        return _this;
      };
      this.start = function(refresh) {
        if (refresh == null) {
          refresh = _this.options.refresh || $.countdown.defaultOptions.refresh;
        }
        if (_this.interval) {
          clearInterval(_this.interval);
        }
        _this.render();
        _this.options.refresh = refresh;
        _this.interval = setInterval(function() {
          return _this.render();
        }, _this.options.refresh);
        return _this;
      };
      return this.init();
    };
    $.countdown.defaultOptions = {
      date: "June 7, 2087 15:03:25",
      refresh: 1000,
      render: function(date) {
        _hey_html = "";
        if(date.years > 0){
          _hey_html += '<span class="countdown-years" title="years left">' + date.years + 'year </span>';
        }
        return $(this.el).html(_hey_html+'<span class="countdown-days" title="days left">  ' + date.days + ' </span><span class="countdown-hours" title="hours left"> ' + (this.leadingZeros(date.hours)) + '<small> h </small> </span><span class="countdown-min" title="minutes left">' + (this.leadingZeros(date.min)) + '<small> m </small> </span><span class="countdown-sec" title="seconds left">' + (this.leadingZeros(date.sec)) + '<small> s </small></span>');
      }
    };
    $.fn.countdown = function(options) {
      return $.each(this, function(i, el) {
        var $el;
        $el = $(el);
        if (!$el.data('countdown')) {
          return $el.data('countdown', new $.countdown(el, options));
        }
      });
    };
    return void 0;
  })(jQuery);

}).call(this);
```

I think there should be some kind of delay when parsing dates in this plugin, dates are PHP generated as Unixtimestamp then I do this:

```
$(function(){
  $.each($('.countdown'), function() {
    var _element = '.countdown-'+$(this).attr("id");
    var _id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(_element).length > 0){
      var _datetime = $(_element).attr('data-expiration').toLocaleString();
      var d = new Date(_datetime).getTime();

      var result = new Date(d);
      _datetime = d;
      init_countdown(_id,_element,_datetime);

    }
  });
});
```

this is the html

```
<div data-expiration="Jan 01, 2013 20:01:15" id="25" class="span12    countdown label-expiring  countdown-25">
```

Sometimes it doesn't shows the real dates, it seems is in delay of about 20/30 minutes, and I can't understand why.

Any help appriaciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you post values of the `data-expiration` attribute along with string representations of the corresponding dates that are created in JS for both inaccurate and accurate countdown values?

Comment: @tiffon i added the html element where to bind up the plugin, you can try with different **data-expiration** and you will check that sometimes it is not accurate or maybe never accurated at all, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not quite understand, why in your code had so many passages from date to date?
 if your "tag attribute" was already with a correct date format.

I've done some adjustments in the source code, I've tested and I do not see any kind of delay in the source code or in the plugin.

This is the source code and you can test here:

- [**simple mode**](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgQ3/1/)
- [**full mode**](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgQ3/)
- [**mixed mode**](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgQ3/2/)

```
function init_countdown(id,element,datetime,fullmode){
    var endDate = datetime;
    if(!fullmode){
       $(element).countdown({ date: endDate });
    }else{
        $(element).countdown({
          date: endDate,
          render: function(data) {
            var el = $(this.el);
            el.empty()
              .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.years, 4) + " <span>years</span></div>")
              .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.days, 3) + " <span>days</span></div>")
              .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.hours, 2) + " <span>hrs</span></div>")
              .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.min, 2) + " <span>min</span></div>")
              .append("<div>" + this.leadingZeros(data.sec, 2) + " <span>sec</span></div>");
          }
        });
    }
 }


$(function(){
  var mode=1;
  $.each($('.countdown'), function() {
    var _element = '.countdown-'+$(this).attr("id");
    var _id = $(this).attr("id");
    if($(_element).length > 0){
      var _datetime = $(_element).attr('data-expiration');
      init_countdown(_id,_element,_datetime,(mode^=1));
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
  <body>
      <div id="25" class="span12 countdown label-expiring countdown-25" data-expiration="Jan 01, 2014 20:01:15">
      </div>
      <hr />
      <div id="26" class="span12 countdown label-expiring countdown-26" data-expiration="Jan 01, 2015 20:01:15">
      </div>
      <hr />      
       <div id="27" class="span12 countdown label-expiring countdown-27" data-expiration="Jan 01, 2016 20:01:15">
      </div>
  </body>​
```

Comment: great, i can't understand why render: option doesn't works then :P

Comment: In the example that I have posted, if you see the "init_countdown" there is a parameter called "fullmode" this mode allows working with the render, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgQ3/) you can see the example with the three timers in complete form, and in the other example may you see a [mixed mode](http://jsfiddle.net/8HgQ3/2/). I hope I have been helpful